# Is there a way to insert/update data from apex_application_page_ir_rpt

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-20.2

Our client have a requirement to share Saved Report from user to another user. I am thinking of inserting the data for USER2 copied from the data of USER1 from apex_application_page_ir_rpt. Is it possible? Please see the attached photo. USER2 must be able to see what the USER1 is viewing.[image]

Comment: I assume you can't authorize USER1 to create public saved reports?
I think you'd have to create an update function to write that data to the underlying Apex table, then grant that right to your user. Not something out-of-the-box.

Comment: If APEX doesn't provide an API to do that, a custom solution may not work as intended. You don't know what APEX is doing on the back end to provision each report; simply copying a couple rows of data in one table is unlikely to be a complete solution.

Comment: There is an API to change the owner, but not to copy a report. APEX_IR package can also be used to add_filter, so you could potentially use the dictionary table to recreate the filters. But like Stew says, saving a public report seems like a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I am not sure I quiet understood, this table APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_RPT is a view and need to know how it is populated, what table does it call. My target is to have a button to copy the report(all conditions and filters) to another user. I am trying to recreate it using wwv_flow_worksheet_** tables. I'm lost. Can you please help me?